# Makefile fails executing sudo docker kill

Tags: docker, makefile

I am trying to execute the next Makefile, but when I run the docker kill it fails because don't detect the "$(sudo docker ps -q)" or it does not execute this part.

I have the next Makefile:

```
.PHONY: kill all services farr-api farr-ingest farr-from-on-premise farr-real-time-processing

farr-api:
        cd apis/1api && sudo docker-compose up -d

farr-ingest:
        cd apis/2ingest && sudo docker-compose up -d

farr-from-on-premise:
        cd apis/3onpremise && sudo docker-compose up -d

farr-real-time-processing:
        cd apis/4realtimeprocessing && sudo docker-compose up -d

services:
        cd services && sudo docker-compose up -d

all: services farr-from-on-premise farr-real-time-processing farr-ingest farr-api

kill: 
       sudo docker kill $(sudo docker ps -q)
```

When I run `make kill` it throws the next error:

```
   sudo docker kill 
"docker kill" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker kill --help'.

Usage:  docker kill [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Kill one or more running containers
make: *** [kill] Error 1
```

It looks like "$" does not detect by Makefile.
But if I run manually sudo docker kill $(sudo docker ps -q) it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target should look like this:

```
kill:
    for c in $$(sudo docker ps -q); do sudo docker kill $$c; done
```

UPDATE:
turns out that `docker kill` works with multiple containers as arguments, so just escaping dollar is enough to kill all containers

```
kill:
    sudo docker kill $$(sudo docker ps -q)
```

Comment: Sorry, my problem is the next, I have edited the post.

Comment: in this case, just enumerate all `ps` results. But in general it is not good practice to use sudo in makefiles. After all it will ask you type in password every time (unless you tell sudo not to do it, which lowers security)

Comment: The sudo docker kill $$(sudo docker ps -q) works for me. Really thanks